# How to preview files before uploaded to server by using file-upload component of vue.js & element-ui?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using vue.js & element-ui to upload files and preview files. I want to preview file(.pdf/.docx/.jpg...) before uploaded to server.

```html
 <el-upload
          ref="uploadFile"
          :on-change="onUploadChange"
          :on-preview="handlePreview"
          :on-remove="handleRemove"
          :before-remove="beforeRemove"
          :file-list="fileList"
          :http-request="handleUpload"
          :data="extendData"
          :auto-upload="false"
          class="upload-demo"
          drag
          action="uploadUrl"
          multiple>
          <i class="el-icon-upload"/>
          <div class="el-upload__text">drag here, or <em>click to upload</em></div>
 </el-upload>
```

Only the on-change function can get the content of the file, while the on-preview function only get the meta message. How to get the file content and preview that before which is uploaded to server?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `meta`, it's the file. So you need to use a `FileReader` on the `file`:

```
handlePreview(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onload = e => console.log(e.target.result) // here is the result you can work with.

  reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

Comment: I got error message: TypeError: reader.readFile is not a function while running the code. I change the 'reader.readFile()' to  'reader.readAsText(file, 'gbk')', but which still has some mistakes:  Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'. Is there any advice?

Comment: I got a solution to solve this problem -- save file object in a variable in onUploadChange function, and I can get the file object from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Element-UI upload box, the following code allow user to import a JSON file to Vue, and preview its content in a new window when clicking the file name. The file is read and stored as object in `data` during `on-change`, then

Vue component:

```html
<el-upload class="upload-box" drag action="" :auto-upload="false" :on-change="handleImport" :on-preview="handlePreview" :limit="1" :on-exceed="handleExceed">
<i class="el-icon-upload"></i>
<div class="el-upload__text">Drop file here or <em>click to upload</em></div>
<div class="el-upload__tip" slot="tip">Single JSON file with size less than 500kb</div>
</el-upload>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      uploadFile: null,
      fileContent: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleImport(file) {
      this.uploadFile = file
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsText(this.uploadFile.raw)
      reader.onload = async (e) => {
        try {
          this.fileContent = JSON.parse(e.target.result)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(`Load JSON file error: ${err.message}`)
        }
      }
    },
    handlePreview() {
      let myWindow = window.open();
      myWindow.document.write(JSON.stringify(this.fileContent));
      myWindow.document.close();
    },
    handleExceed(files, fileList) {
      this.$message.warning(`The limit is 1, you selected ${files.length + fileList.length} totally, please first remove the unwanted file`);
    },
  },
}
```